# Maven error when building project

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea

I am new to using Selenium and Maven and am stuck on the very first step.

I have created a new Maven project using IntelliJ IDEA. When I try to build the project I receive the error attached. Is this related to network security?

Many thanks for any help.[image]

Comment: post text, not image.

Comment: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-proxies.html

Answer (score 0):

Please see error below:

Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/
plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom

[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------

[INFO] BUILD FAILURE

[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------

[INFO] Total time: 04:01 min

[INFO] Finished at: 2018-03-06T14:20:13Z

[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/15M

[INFO] ----------------------------------------------------

[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connection reset -> [Help 1]

Comment: You have a problem with your network connection either missing configuration for proxy/firewall..that's issue you have...